# MVC project, must add reference to PresentationFramework, WindowsBase errors

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, build-process

I have an MVC project that has been working for years that I just re-published to the server yesterday. I opened it up to debug and make changes to code. Some time in between compiles, something happened and now the build fails complaining that

> The type 'System.Windows.FrameworkElement' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'PresentationFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

and

> The type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I have looked at similar questions and done as they have suggested to make sure all files are set to the Build Action compile, content or none for the project. I didn't add any new files and I didn't copy paste any images into solution.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Not sure if this will be helpful. I didn't include it because it doesn't seem like it would be, but this is where it takes  me when I double click on the errors given.

```
    public PartialViewResult GetByJobID(int jobID)
    {
        ViewBag.Jobid = jobID;
        var getAllHolesByJobID = _toolCalloutService.getAllJobHoles(jobID);
        var toolOrderHoleViewModels = //error happens here on var
            getAllHolesByJobID.Select(Mapper.Map<HoleInfoViewModel, ToolOrderHoleViewModel>).ToList();
        var shipOrigins = _toolCalloutService.GetDistricts();
        ViewData["ToolOrderHoleViewModels"] = toolOrderHoleViewModels;
        ViewData["ShipOrigins"] = shipOrigins;
        ViewData["OrderedBy"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.Substring(9);
        return PartialView("~/Views/ToolCallout/ToolCallout.cshtml");
    }
```

It just highlights the `var` keyword at `var toolOrderHoleViewModels`.

Comment: We can't answer the question _"What happened?"_. Compare your local version against Source Control to see the changes. You most likely made a typo and Alt+Entered that to let ReSharper import a WPF assembly, which you don't want for a web application. If you don't have source control, let this be a lesson to start using it. If you want help on solving the issue, you need to show the relevant code that causes these compiler errors.

Comment: Why do you need System.Windows.FrameworkElement in an MVC site?

Comment: Thats what i thought... thats WPF

Comment: That's exactly the problem. I don't need or want WPF anything. I discarded all changes from source control, but the change is in the dll. I was hoping someone might have something I can try to fix it.

Comment: Regarding your edit: it seems like either `HoleInfoViewModel` or `ToolOrderHoleViewModel` (i.e. the one the mapper maps to, so I guess the latter) uses dependency properties. Did those classes get any edits lately?

Comment: No those files are unchanged. If it were that I accidentally imported a WPF assembly, would there be any way to weed it out?